# Converts old style lists to the new easier to understand format

Tags: python

The old list format looked like:

```
['Item 1', [['Item 1.1', []], ['Item 1.2', []]]]
```

And it is supposed be converted to:

```
['Item 1', ['Item 1.1', 'Item 1.2']]
```

This question comes from Django's ource code but I have trouble figuring it out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give more context on where you see this, and what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: The first piece of code is not a list - there is an inconsistency between opening and closing square brackets.

Comment: I see this from Django Built-in template filters. Now i get trouble in converting the list, I have try many way,including recusion,but nothing help.

Comment: Is it always exactly like this? I.e. you'll always want to grab the same three items from the same places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option... this will also keep the format you request, and should work with any number of sub-items, but since I lack an example with more complex sub-items, I don't know if it will hold with real data... you'd have to check!

```
test = ['Item 1', [['Item 1.1', []], ['Item 1.2', []]]]

def convert(oldlist, newlist):
    for i in range(len(oldlist)):
        if type(oldlist[i]) == list and type(oldlist[i][0]) != list:
            newlist.append(oldlist[i][0])
        elif type(oldlist[i]) != list:
            newlist.append(oldlist[i])
        else:
            newlist.append([])
            convert(oldlist[i], newlist[-1])
    return newlist

print(convert(test, []))
```

Output is:

`['Item 1', ['Item 1.1', 'Item 1.2']]`

Comment: Thanks a lot.This really help.(Sorry for that i dont't have enough permission to vote this answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools

l = ['Item 1', [['Item 1.1', []], ['Item 1.2', []]]]

def con(L):
    res = []
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            temp = list(itertools.chain(*x))
            res.extend(temp)
        else:
            res.append(x)
    return [x for x in res if x]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(con(l))
```

the output is:
`['Item 1', 'Item 1.1', 'Item 1.2']`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
test = ['Item 1', [['Item 1.1', []], ['Item 1.2', []]]]

def convert(oldlist):
    return [oldlist[0], [oldlist[1][0][0], oldlist[1][1][0]]]

print(convert(test))
```

Output is:

`['Item 1', ['Item 1.1', 'Item 1.2']]`